# INSERT after importing phpMyAdmin export not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

I'm using PDO::exec() to import tables from a phpMyAdmin export and right after inserting data into one of those tables. Every time I try to import the file it seems to truncate the tables it made after inserting since a select statement right after the inserts shows the rows correctly. However the table is empty if I look at it manually after running the script even if I exit the script right after the inserts. Please note that I do not get any errors from running the script or running the SQL import file manually.

I couldn't find anything about this issue. I hope someone has an answer. Thanks in advance.

PHP

```
$db->exec(file_get_contents('test.sql'));

$db->query("
    INSERT INTO test 
    SET
        test1 = 5,
        test2 = 'testing123'
");
```

phpMyAdmin export

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `test`
--

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test2` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Indexen voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- Indexen voor tabel `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor een tabel `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Have a look at the export - does it probably contain something like `DROP TABLE` or `TRUNCATE`? That's usual for a full export of a table coming from phpMyAdmin

Comment: "I'd rather not share my code here unless absolutely needed" . It is absolutely needed.

Comment: @NicoHaase It doesn't drop or truncate the table anywhere in the export or in my code. Even if it did, the inserts are done after that script is supposed to be done running so that would mean they are running out of order.

Comment: Edit: Remove / change any passwords or access details or non-relevant URI's to your code before showing it

Comment: @Martin I will try to recreate the problem using a smaller script

Comment: Well, if neither the data you import nor the code you've written contains anything to drop or truncate tables, there is no reason for them to be empty. But as you don't want to show any of that code, there is no way to help you

Comment: @NicoHaase I was able to recreate it with a small script that I have no added to the question

Comment: @Martin I added some code that recreates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to have been caused by the line `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;` in the export file. I don't have enough knowledge of MySQL to know what exactly it does but everything still seems to work without it.

Comment: `AUTOCOMMIT=0` expects you to eventually issue `COMMIT`.  I don't see that in the code.